# Can you save different object transform states similar to shape keys?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

So I am making a plane, and I want to easily scroll between the landing gear being open and closed. I want something similar to shape keys, in that I can pull a slider, and it goes from one rotation state to another. The problem is that I cannot just rotate it in edit mode and use shape keys because I need the effect to alter the actual rotational values of the object, as it is a parent for multiple smaller objects.
Is there a way I can store different states of a objects rotation similarly to shape keys, but outside of edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, by "outside of Edit Mode" you mean to alter object properties, as opposed to the mesh data. This is done in Blender by parenting and empties.

[image]

If you want a slider, then use a custom property and a driver.

[image]